# Bootstrap 5 modal on ReactJS component with custom isOpen props not showing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap v5.0.0-beta3 in my NextJS app template and I created a component with Bootstrap's modal like this

```js
import ProductModel from "@/model/ProductModel";
import React from "react";

interface Props {
    modalId: string
    product: ProductModel | null,
    onClose: () => void
}

const AddToCartModal = ({ modalId = 'addToCart', product, onClose }: Props) => {
    const isOpen = product != null
    const modalLabel = `${modalId}Label`
    const modalClassName = `modal fade ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`;

    return (
        <div className={modalClassName} id={modalId} tabIndex={-1} aria-labelledby={modalLabel} aria-hidden={!isOpen}>
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title" id={modalLabel}>{product?.name}</h5>
                        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onClick={() => onClose()}></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        {/* ... */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={() => onClose()}>Close</button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddToCartModal;
```

as you can see, I have a `isOpen` variable in it, now even if that `isOpen` variable is true, the modal isn't showing.

I checked the inspect element and I see that the `.modal` class was still in `display: none`

did I do it right? or what's the problem with my code?
or do you have any alternative method for this function?

Comment: Can you expand code for what calls the `AddToCartModal` or provide logs of what the values are inside `AddToCartModal`?